# Nodejs Promise.All with promise chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch

I'm not sure how to ask this question, but I have a set of promises that all need to be resolved as they are data api requests, but one of the three depends on the other and I'm not sure how to resolve.

The code in question looks like this:

```
    let dependent;

    let subscriptions = getSubscriptions() //data fetch
       .then((subscriptions) => {
            let fieldList = subscriptions.reduce((subscription) => {
               if(subscription.Threshold) {
                  return subscription.Threshold.Field;
               }
               return null;
           });
           dependent = getUpdatedInfo(request, body, fieldList); //Data fetch promise
           return subscriptions;
       });

    let userInfo = getUserInformation(); //Data fetch

    Promise.all([subscriptions, userInfo, dependent]).then(function(values) {
        console.log({ promiseAll: values }); //Dependent is always undefined
        processSubscriptions(result, body, userInfo, subscriptions, dependent);
    });
```

I have tried this code a few different ways based on the last 4 hours of googling, but haven't quite figured out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: If one of them depends on the others, then it's not part of the original Promise.all set, because it can't be. So you get `Promise.all([independent tasks]).then(results => promiseBasedOn(results)).then( data => now we're done )`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Wow. I am an idiot. Would you mind putting this as an answer?

Comment: not sure this constitutes a real question, honestly. The problem was mostly you forgot to order things. It's got a bunch of downvotes, too, so probably more productive to delete it again?

Comment: I suppose if you don't want the credit, hah

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with raw Promises, but it's kinda ugly. Much neater with async/await:

```
async function whatever() {
  const subs = await getSubscriptions();
  const fieldList = subs.reduce((subscription) => {
    if(subscription.Threshold) {
      return subscription.Threshold.Field;
    }
      return null;
    });
  const dependent = await getUpdatedInfo(request, body, fieldList);
  const userInfo = await getUserInfo();
  return processSubscriptions(result, body, userInfo, subscriptions, dependent);
}
```

Comment: I am forced to use promise here as the fetch api is promise-based

Comment: @CBauer async/await *is* Promises. It's just syntactic sugar over `.then`.

Comment: @CBauer `async/await` is a syntax sugar for `Promise`, therefore this is correct.

Comment: This should work but doesn't achieve the parallelization so would be slower.

Comment: @FakeFootball slower? Yes. Slower enough to matter? Probably not. I'm not going to sacrifice clean readable code for speed until a profiler tells me I need to.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS in non-blocking. All lines are executed synchronously, and `dependent` is surely undefined in `Promise.all` call because it was set to `undefined` in line `let dependent;`

`.then` callback is executed asynchronously, e.g. **after** all synchronous code.

If you want to use `dependent` which is resolved in `then` then you have to chain `then` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor with async/await. To achieve the parallelization you are looking for we create two promises for (userInfo and dependent) and then use promise.All to await their resolution. promise.All returns an array of the result of all the promises.

Make sure to use a try, catch

```
async function processSubscriptionsHandler(request, body) {
    try {
        let userInfoPromise = getUserInformation(); // async function returning a promise
        let subscriptions = await getSubscriptions()
        let fieldList = getFieldList(subscriptions)
        let dependentPromise = getUpdatedInfo(request, body, fieldList) // async function returning a promise

        let [userInfo, dependent] = await Promise.all([userInfoPromise, dependentPromise]) // await both promises to resolve and map resulting array to variables

        processSubscriptions(result,
            body,
            userInfo,
            subscriptions,
            dependent);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}

function getFieldList(subscriptions) {
    subscriptions.reduce((subscription) => {
        if (subscription.Threshold) {
            return subscription.Threshold.Field;
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to rejig your logic into promises -- one of the tools you can use for a chain of dependent promises is to declare your variables before the promise, and then set them in the `.then` -- that way the variable is available for all closures in the code block:

```
let subscriptions;
let updatedInfo;
let subscriptionsPromise = getSubscriptions() //data fetch
   .then((subscriptionsResults) => {
        let fieldList = subscriptionsResults.reduce((subscription) => {
           if(subscription.Threshold) {
              return subscription.Threshold.Field;
           }
           return null;
       });
       subscriptions = subscriptionsResults
       return getUpdatedInfo(request, body, fieldList); //Data fetch promise
   })
   .then(updatedInfoResult => {
       updatedInfo = updatedInfoResult;
   });

let userInfoPromise = getUserInformation(); //Data fetch

Promise.all([subscriptionsPromise, userInfoPromise]).then(function(values) {
    // at this point, subscriptions should have a value, 
    // and so should updatedInfo,
    // and values[1] should be the result from userInfoPromise
});
```